# Generic constructor: T entity = new T();

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, constraints

I have the following winforms classes:

```
class EntityEditorForm<T>: System.Windows.Forms.Form 
                              where T: ICloneable<T> {}

class EntityCollectionEditorForm<T> : System.Windows.Forms.Form 
                                      where T: ICloneable<T> {}
```

The first form class is an editor for `<T>` that creates controls at run-time depending on the type of T.

The second is a manager for a collection of `<T>` and has Add, Edit and Delete functions. The collection is displayed in a listview control with fields populated through reflection using custom attributes.

The code for Add and Edit buttons looks like this:

```
private void buttonEdit_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   T entity = default(T);  
   entity = (T) this.listView.SelectedItems[0].Tag;  
   new EntityEditor<T>(entity).ShowDialog(this);  
}

private void buttonEdit_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   T entity = new T();   //This is the code which is causing issues 
   entity = (T) this.listView.SelectedItems[0].Tag;  
   new EntityEditor<T>(entity).ShowDialog(this);  
}
```

The `default(T)` works in the case of edit but I'm having trouble with the Add scenario. `T entity = new T();` does not appear to be legal.

Comment: Apparently, I did not know how to add multiple constraints within the same where clause. Modifying the declaration to `class EntityCollectionEditorForm < T > : System.Windows.Forms.Form where T: ICloneable < T >, new() {}` worked.

Comment: I've been reading articles but can't seem to get a grasp on constraints. Any lay-man explanations would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your type contains an parameterless constructor, you can add a constraint onto your generic type `T` to allow instantiation through this parameterless constructor. To do this, add the constraint:

```
where T : new()
```

MSDN Article on [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: Note that "empty constructor" should really be "parameterless constructor" - otherwise it sounds like it has to have no code.

Comment: @Slade, thanks. I stumbled upon the answer as I was finishing up the question but this would have definitely saved time had that not happened. Given my unfamiliarity with constraints, this would probably be useful to enough people.

Comment: How does up-voting on questions work in SO? Do you 'like' questions, etc.?

Comment: @RaheelKhan Upvoting is when you click the upward arrow. It essentially shows that you've marked the post as a useful question/answer (depending on what you've upvoted). It is useful for others that stumble across it. It also adds to a user's reputation, which allows for other's on SO to see which users normally provide good answers. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) section with regards to reputation.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Upvoting a question means that you think it's a "good" question (it's worth asking), that the question is concise and clear, and that it shows initial research effort (i.e. you didn't post it here just because you were too lazy to Google it).